# Incremental Load vs Partial Load in QlikView

Tags: load, qlikview

What is the difference between the two. In which scenarios we use the above two.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Incremental load**

This type of load is usually used when extracting data. Instead getting all the data from the database every time when the app is reloaded *incremental load* can be set to get only the *new, updated or deleted* records and store them locally. *Incremental load* is not a function of QV/QS its a technique that can be used/set during the data extraction phase (usually used when fairly big data sets)

**Partial reload**

This is an actual QV/QS function and the documentation for it can be found [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/November2017/Subsystems/Client/Content/Partial%20Reload.htm)

*Partial reload* is somehow similar to the *Incremental load* and its used to `add` data to existing QV data table or `replace` data table completely but leaving all other tables (the ones without `Add` or `Replace` prefix) intact. *Partial reload* can be invoked via `File --> Partial reload` or `Ctrl+Shift+R`